# Makefile saying Missing Operator

Tags: c, linux, unix, makefile

I am trying to run a makefile that compiles these 'C' programs at the same time.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = queue.h

all: \threadss

threadss: thread.o queueImp.o
    $(CC) thread.o queueImp.o -o threadss

thread.o: thread.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) threads.c

thread.o: queueImp.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) queueImp.c

clean:
    rm -rf *o threadss
```

However the following error is returned:

```
Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Please help me to  solve this. I am using the unix environment.

Comment: the `\ ` in `all: \threadss` shouldn't be there.

Comment: there is also no indications that `DEPS` is used at all, ususally you don'T have to specified the rules for object files (*.o) as the rules are implicit, and your clean rule shouldl remove *.o (not *o as it is too broad)

Answer (score 16):

makefile needs a `tab` before every command of a rule.  Make sure there **is** a `tab` [not spaces] before `$(CC) thread.o queueImp.o -o threadss` and other commands.

Note: Usually, the clean command is used to remove object files having `.o` extensions. maybe what you want is

```
 rm -rf *.o threadss
         ^
         |
```

to serve the actual purpose.